# How do I make sure the rapidly changing data from my MySQL DB is accurately represented in php scripts?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with lots of game objects,
which is being queried by the following 3 PHP scripts.

1. **List objects:** gets a JSON object with all the items I need
2. **Add object:** adds an object to the database
3. **Reset:** wipes all objects from the table

All three of them work, somewhat. Although, there is a timing mismatch. When the game calls the reset function, it restarts. When the game restarts, it automatically loads all the objects. Unfortunately,and here's the problem, if the game has just been reset, objects will still be pulled by script 1.

I know *of* transactions, but I have never used them and I have no idea how I would implement those here, since my transaction is involving things from different scripts that are run at different times.

For bonus credit: will this setup (AS3 > php > MySQL) get me in trouble with a heavy load? The game might get picked up by 10, 100, 1000 people, is there anything I can read about that subject?

**Edit: new idea/question**

Currently, the wiping works as such: The objects table has a field 'deleted' which is set to '1' when the reset method is called. It might be smarter to copy the existing data into an archive table and then truncate the live table...

**Edit: Here's the (relevant) PHP code I'm using**

Add Object:

```
if ($db_found) {

$x = $_GET['x'];
$y = $_GET['y'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$text = $_GET['text'];

$SQL = "INSERT INTO bodies  (x,y,type,name,text)
VALUES ('".$x."','".$y."','".$type."','".$name."','".$text."' )";

if (!mysql_query($SQL))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

};

mysql_close($db_handle);
```

List/Get Objects:

```
if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM bodies WHERE deleted = 0";
$res = mysql_query($SQL);

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        print $r['x'] . ','
        . $r['y']
        . ','
        . $r['type']
        . ','
        . $r['name']
        . ','
        . $r['text']
        .  ';';
    }

};
mysql_close($db_handle);
```

Reset: **(EDIT 2)**

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES bodies WRITE;");

$SQL = " DELETE FROM bodies";

if (!mysql_query($SQL))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
};

mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES;");
```

Comment: Can you add the code ???? Form what i see .. you need to introduce .. game `session` and also `clear` cache ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to do Transactions in MySQL.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html)

In your case you might be interessted in the atomicity and isolation of transactions, meaning that when restarting a game, you want to ensure that before the reset has not fully finished, nobody can fetch any of your intermediate data. Doing the reset inside a transaction will ensure this property*. (* for TRUNCATE see below)

You will need InnoDB as your Engine for all tables that are involved in your transactions. MyISAM does not support transactions.

Changing large amounts of data inside a transaction can potentially cause high query delays, as transaction use special undo/redo-logs to be able to undo all the things you did in your transaction, if you decide to `ROLLBACK`.

I wouldn't wipe the tables when starting a new game. Instead give your data a `game_id` and use a new `game_id` when starting a new game. Space shouldn't really be an issue nowadays. This has the advantage that you will need little to none table [locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) when reseting the game.

If you must, be sure to use `TRUNCATE` when clearing out the tables. As far as I know `TRUNCATE` in MySQL cannot be rolled back, so doing it inside a transaction won't do anything useful.

I think PHP/MySQL will perform fine if used correctly, even for larger visitor counts. You can use profiling tools like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or the [MySQL slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) to trace and remove performance bottle necks.

Comment: To be clear, the List Objects and Add Objects will be accessed much more frequently than the 'Reset' one. Is there a way to, when reset is called, make currently running scripts restart or fail?
(This was exactly the type of answer I was looking for, thanks so much. )

Comment: Yes you can lock the tables you want to prevent from beeing accessed while reseting. See [MySQL's manual on locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html).

Comment: The thing you are talking about in your first edit is called a "shadow table". Found [this link](http://arnab.org/node/1169) for mysql. Seeing your code you should also thoroughly read [about SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Incorrect_type_handling). :-)

Comment: Yeah, I realise the lack of security, thanks for reminding me. We are in very early prototyping phase, but still, there's no excuse really ;)

Comment: Hmmm... so I updated the php code in the post, but it doesn't seem to work. When I do Get Objects quickly after a reset, the values are still there...

Comment: I didn't use table locks with MySQL yet so I'm not sure about this. Do you use `mysql_pconnect` to build a connection? Persistent connections probably share table locks. What engine do you use for your tables? Have you tried InnoDB?

Comment: Instead of using `DELETE` to remove all tuples, use `TRUNCATE`. It's way faster.

Comment: So I did a local test and using `mysql_pconnect` seemed not to have any effect. Both `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` blocked the reading query for until the other script did the unlock. For testing purposes you can do a `sleep(10)` right before your `UNLOCK` to wait for 10 seconds. You should see that your reading script will now be blocked for the same time. If it isn't, you didn't acquire the lock. Are you sure that you have the necessary rights?

Comment: TRUNCATE doesn't work with triggers in our version of MySQL (I found the bug report where they fixed it and we're using an older version).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10029/discussion-between-joon-and-basti)